# sending pdf in json from symfony to angular

Tags: json, angular, symfony, fpdf

i working on a project with symfony and angular and i want to send a pdf file in json or another way to send it from my backend to frontend app .

i won't try to save it on the server and send just the url to access . what i want is to send it on json data .

for more details i using FPDF to generate pdf file and i want to to it in json .
this is my controller :

```
/**
     * @Get("/testt")
     */
    public function test2Action()
    {
        $pdf = new \FPDF('P','mm','A4');
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Image(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/assets/images/icons8-Calendar Filled-50.png');
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
        $pdf->SetXY(25,12);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode('Evénements'));
        $pdf->SetXY(10,25);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode("72eordre"));
        $pdf->SetXY(12,42);
        $pdf->Image(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/assets/images/icons8-Marker-50.png',null,null,-150);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);$pdf->SetTextColor(110,110,110);
        $pdf->SetXY(22,36);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode(" Grand Palais"));
        $pdf->SetXY(22,41);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode("saada 458"));
        $pdf->SetXY(22,46);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode("59000, marrakech-"));
        $pdf->SetXY(12,61);
        $pdf->Image(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/assets/images/calendar-gris.png',null,null,-150);

        $pdf->SetXY(22,58);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode("Du 27 septembre 2017 à 08:00"));
        $pdf->SetXY(22,63);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode("Au 29 semptembre 2017 à 18:00"));

        $pdf->SetXY(10,80);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);$pdf->SetFont('');$pdf->SetTextColor(110,110,110);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,utf8_decode("Cette carte"));
         $pdf->SetXY(10,85);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,utf8_decode(" obtenir votre badge "));
        $pdf->SetXY(25,96);
        $pdf->Image(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/assets/qrcode.png',null,null,-220);
        $pdf->SetXY(25,160);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(1,49,180);
        $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.2835);
        $pdf->Rect(12,160,85,20, "F");
        $pdf->SetXY(14,161);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,utf8_decode("yassine "));
        $pdf->SetXY(14,168);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);$pdf->SetFont('');
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,utf8_decode("CHEF DE PROJET "));
        $pdf->SetDrawColor(150,150,150);
        $pdf->Line(10, 25, 100, 25);
        $pdf->Line(10, 35, 100, 35);
        $pdf->Line(15, 55, 100, 55);
        $pdf->Line(10, 75, 100, 75);
        return new Response($pdf->Output(), 200, array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
    }
```

as you can see , the reponse type isby default in the FPDF api : application/pdf

so what is the solution to send this file and access from the frontend that is angular  2.3

Comment: What's the problem? What Angular is supposed to do with this PDF?

Comment: download it or show it in the browser

Answer (score 1):

The safe way to embed a PDF into a JSON response is to encode it into base64 format. After that you can parse the response on a client side, decode the PDF data and do whatever you want with a PDF content.

```
return new JsonResponse(['data' => base64_encode($pdf->Output())]);
```

Comment: this is not working  , it still application/pdf in the type of the response

Comment: Please make sure you're returning a JsonResponse instead of Response. JsonResponse should set application/json content type by default.

Comment: If you're using a code snipper from my answer, there is no possible way to get a response with application/pdf content type. (except of some kernel event listeners) Please update your question with your code, probably this will help to find an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Previous response is correct, we work like that in many company, you can also use the shortcut provided by the ControllerTrait of FrameworkBundle for render JsonResponse :

```
return $this->json(['data' => base64_encode($pdf->Output())]);
```

But, in 2019, we have many mobile app's, base64 encoded is not a good solution, the phone can burn considerating the big size of base64 (33% bigest of original content).

For solution we do not use REST with JSON but simply serve the file with BinaryFileResponse (that set automatically the correct content-type)

```
public function downloadAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    /** @var MessageFile $file */
    $file = $em->getRepository(MessageFile::class)->findFile(
        $request->attributes->get('id')
    );

    return new BinaryFileResponse($file->getPath());
}
```

In your Angular App, just call downloadAction.